# Left-aligning Beamer titles with text

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

How can I set things up so that my `\frametitle` has the same indentation as the main body of text in my slide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\setbeamersize` to change the value of `text margin left` so that the tile and the left margin have the same value; depending on the used theme, you will have to adjust the value for `text margin left`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to redefine the `frametitle`of the template via `\setbeamertemplate`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle} 
\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Hallo Welt!}

\blindtext
}

\end{document}
```

If you are using an existing template, have a look for this command in the corresponding style file and adjust it accordingly.

[image: result of setbeamertemplate]